# ACL/MAC Permissions for dovecot and postfix in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, email, postfix, dovecot

I am using [this tutorial to set up `Postfix` and `Dovecot` on a `CentOS 7` web server](https://www.vultr.com/docs/simple-mailserver-postfix-dovecot-sieve-centos-7).  But when I try to send a test email using `sudo echo "TEST" | mail -s "testmail" newuser@localhost && sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog`, I get an error indicating that Dovecot does not have permissions to create the directory for storing the email.  How do I go about setting up permissions for `Dovecot` and `Postfix` to be able to work properly in `CentOS 7`?

I am new to `linux`.  I know about `adduser`, `chmod`, `chown`, `octal permissions`, and other commands, but I do not know how they all apply to this specific requirement, and I do not want to create ineffective things by experimenting without understanding.

Here is the most relevant part of the error message:

```
Error: user import: Initialization failed: Namespace '':  
mkdir(/home/import/Maildir) failed:  
Permission denied (euid=1001(import) egid=1001(import)  
missing +w perm: /home/import, UNIX perms appear ok (ACL/MAC wrong?))
```

Here is the complete error message:

```
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain postfix/pickup[8093]: A22E78221C13: uid=1000 from=<anotherusername>
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain postfix/cleanup[8121]: A22E78221C13: message-id=<20141231000342.A22E78221C13@mydomain.com>
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain postfix/qmgr[8094]: A22E78221C13: from=<anotherusername@mydomain.com>, size=463, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Error: user newusername: Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/home/newusername/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1001(newusername) egid=1001(newusername) missing +w perm: /home/newusername, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Fatal: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Dec 30 19:03:42 mydomain postfix/local[8123]: A22E78221C13: to=<newusername@localhost.com>, orig_to=<newusername@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.06/0.02/0/0.07, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

**EDIT:**

I then ran `sudo chown -R newusername:newusername /home/newusername` and then again repeated `sudo echo "TEST" | sudo mail -s "testmail" newuser@localhost && sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog` but still got the following error:

```
Dec 30 20:42:29 mydomain postfix/qmgr[8094]: E0DF28221C14: from=<anotherusername@mydomain.com>, size=463, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 30 20:42:29 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Error: user newusername: Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/home/newusername/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1001(newusername) egid=1001(newusername) missing +w perm: /home/newusername, UNIX perms appear ok (ACL/MAC wrong?))
Dec 30 20:42:29 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Fatal: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Dec 30 20:42:29 mydomain postfix/local[8531]: E0DF28221C14: to=<newusername@localhost.com>, orig_to=<newusername@localhost>, relay=local, delay=1101, delays=1101/0.02/0/0.06, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain postfix/pickup[8529]: CF3CB80B33C4: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain postfix/cleanup[8551]: CF3CB80B33C4: message-id=<20141231014540.CF3CB80B33C4@mydomain.com>
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain postfix/qmgr[8094]: CF3CB80B33C4: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=455, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Error: user newusername: Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/home/newusername/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1001(newusername) egid=1001(newusername) missing +w perm: /home/newusername, UNIX perms appear ok (ACL/MAC wrong?))
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain dovecot: lda(newusername): Fatal: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Dec 30 20:45:40 mydomain postfix/local[8553]: CF3CB80B33C4: to=<newusername@localhost.com>, orig_to=<newusername@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.15, delays=0.08/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

**ANSWER:**

This problem was due to SELinux.  I resolved the problem by `sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux` and then setting `SELINUX=disabled`.  This is acceptable during development.  A more complete solution will be to set up an SELinux rule allowing postfix and dovecot to function before this goes into production.

Note: Seven-Hundred-and-Forty-Two suggestion that I check SELinux status, so I am marking his as the correct answer.

Comment: Seems you're missing a sudo in `sudo echo "TEST" | mail -s "testmail" newuser@localhost && sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog`.  Try: `echo "TEST" | sudo mail -s "testmail" newuser@localhost && sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is here: `failed: Permission denied (euid=1001(newusername) egid=1001(newusername) missing +w perm: /home/newusername, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755`

Dovecot is trying to write to `/home/newusername/{whatever your maildir is}` as newusername:newusername, however, the directory is owned by user 0:0 (root).  Because the permission mode is 755, only the owner has +w permissions

Also, ensure that if you are using SELinux that your ACLs allow dovecot to write to your maildir

Comment: What do you mean, when no user is logged in?  Dovecot runs in a separate process as the dovecot user.  Dovecot is writing as user 1001 (newusername) which doesn't have write access to your maildir, because root owns it.

Comment: No worries.  Run `chown -R newusername:newusername /home/newusername` as root.  This will change the owner of the newusername's home directory to newusername, recursively

Comment: Can you add the output of `dovecot -n`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19870/discussion-between-seven-hundred-and-forty-two-and-codemed).

Comment: Done.  For the benefit of future users, can you elaborate on what was necessary to allow dovecot to function?

Comment: I just posted the steps for resolving the error at the end of my OP.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same issue.
The parent also mentioned it got it working by disabling selinux. Thank you for the tip. Disabling SEL was not option for me.

So, if you don't want to disable selinux, try:

- check the SELinux context of the "problem" directory:

```
ls -Z /home/newusername
drwx------. centos       centos       unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 centos
drwx------. newusername  newusername  unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 newusername
```

- it should show the `user_home_dir_t` as context
- it should not be the `home_root_t` selinux context.

***Observation:*** If you create the homedir as root, it will pick-up the root context, and then every object created by the user will have the root context.

- to fix this run:

```
restorecon -vR /home/newuserhome
```

- check the SELinux context again, you should have now:

```
ls -Z /home/newusername
drwx------. centos       centos       unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 centos
drwx------. newusername  newusername  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 newusername
```

- **test:** try to create a file or a dir inside `newuserhome` and check SEL context
- if the new file still does not show proper context run:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /home /home/newusername
restorecon -vR /home/newuserhome
```

Hopefully it should have the proper context now for "normal" home-directories and allow access.